# iPhone ModalViewController from First Tab Bar View

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I am trying to launch an initial login/registration screen before my TabBarController View loads. I have read that putting a ModalViewController in the First View is a good way to go. This works, but I am trying to add navigation controls to the ModalViewController. I am getting the following issues:

**1 - ERROR: Property 'navigationController' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate'**

**2 - WARNING: Initializing 'AppDelegate *'with an expression of incompatible type 'id'**

here is the code on my ModalViewController:

```
-(IBAction)signUpButtonTapped {
// i need to get the control for main navigation controller
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
[appDelegate.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
// create object from app main view to push it
SignUpViewController *signUpViewController = [[SignUpViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SignUpViewController" bundle:nil];
[AppDelegate.navigationController pushViewController:signUpViewController animated:YES]; }
```

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks so much!

Comment: typecasting the AppDelegate with `(AppDelegate*)` will solve the warning

Comment: Check out my answer it will solve your error too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There are Two Problems in your code**

1) Accessing the OBJECT with class name. It must be **appDelegate.nav...** (small `a` for Solving 1 ERROR)

```
[appDelegate.navigationController pushViewController:signUpViewController animated:YES];
```

2) Type Casting the assignment (for Solving 2 Warning)

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
```

So your Complete working Code must go as

```
-(IBAction)signUpButtonTapped {
  // i need to get the control for main navigation controller
  AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
  [appDelegate.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
  // create object from app main view to push it
  SignUpViewController *signUpViewController = [[SignUpViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SignUpViewController" bundle:nil];
  [appDelegate.navigationController pushViewController:signUpViewController animated:YES]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Code Modify this Line

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
```

as

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

and try now

Comment: Excellent, that gets rid of my warning, but I still get the error: Property 'navigationController' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate'. I have declared it, but it keeps showing this error. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Are you declared the properties for the Navigationcontroller in Appdelegate

Answer (score 0):

AppDelegate instance declaration is like this:

```
 AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
```

Change this and u r good to go.

Comment: Excellent, that gets rid of my warning, but I still get the error: Property 'navigationController' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate'. I have declared it, but it keeps showing this error. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1.make sure your appDelegate have a `UINavigationController` property called `navigationController`.

2.Line 2 of your code:
`AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];`

3.last line of your code:
`[appDelegate.navigat....` 
NOT:
`[AppDelegate.navigatio....`